# How to autofill a form in Access with data from an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: database, excel, forms, vba, ms-access

I was given an enormous Excel spreadsheet that I have to port to an Access database. There are roughly 40 fields in the spreadsheet per entry. Is it possible to create a form in Access, and use the data from the Excel spreadsheet to automatically populate the form, and in turn, the database?

Answer (score 0):

Using a form for this item by item is a complete waste of time.

On the External Data Tab, you can Import From Excel. If you have a weird layout that doesn't play nice with the Import tool, you can add the Microsoft Excel Object Library and use VBA to open and control Excel Workbook Objects and Worksheet Objects to pull the data in a custom way. Using the second method, I would use a form, but the only purpose for it would be to hold a button that would execute the VBA to import.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ported the entire spreadsheet as is into Access, but I was thinking of breaking it down into multiple tables for easier reading/metrics. In that case, what would you recommend I do to make the transfer of data to different areas the easiest? I'm very new to Access, so I don't have much idea how it works

Comment: I would suggest creating the other tables and then using SQL `INSERT` queries to populate them based off of the data in the spreadsheet e.g. `INSERT INTO (destination) SELECT items FROM sourcetable WHERE something = "what you want"`; alternatively if the data format is always the same just create queries; you can use the query wizard and design tools for that.

Comment: May be a basic question, but how do I actually access the data from the excel spreadsheet when making a query? Do I just import the entire thing into a table and draw the data from there?

Comment: exactly, import into a table and then query the table. If you don't need to dynamically keep track of the excel table this is the easiest way.